# update multiple rows in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to do this

```
User.find([23,45,68,123]).update_all(:is_active => true)
```

but I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `update_all' for #<Array:0x00000007493778>
```

What would be the correct syntax? I would rather not iterate through each one if I don't have to.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`find` returns an array, so you cannot use `update_all`.

To solve the problem, I think you can use `where`, which returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so the `update_all` should work:

```
User.where(:id =>[23,45,68,123]).update_all(:is_active => true)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

I hope it helps...